# Circuit Analysis: Difficulty in obtaining a current through a resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm solving a problem that requires I compute some impedances, and then the current through a resistor. I obtained some of the impedances*, but don't know how to get the second part (current).

---

### Question

[image]

---

### 4.A

For question (A), I partitioned the circuit mostly using intuition. I just kind of chose the left RC to be \$Z_{1}\$, the middle capacitor to be \$Z_{2}\$, and the right-hand RC to be \$Z_{3}\$. The first impedance is wrong, I'm not sure why.

1. $$Z_{1} = \frac{Z_{C}}{Z_{C} + Z_{R}} = \frac{\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{\frac{1}{j \omega C} + R} = \frac{1}{1 + j\omega CR} = \frac{1}{1 + j(\frac{1}{RC})CR} = \frac{1}{1 + j} = \frac{(1 - j)}{2} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}j \rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \angle \frac{-\pi}{4}$$ Actual solution is \$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} R \angle \frac{-\pi}{4}\$
2. $$Z_{2} = \frac{1}{j\omega(\frac{C}{\sqrt{2}})} = ... = 0 - jR\sqrt{2} \rightarrow R\sqrt{2} \angle \frac{-\pi}{2}$$
3. $$Z_{3} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{Z_{R}} + \frac{1}{Z_{C}}} = ... = \frac{R}{2} - j\frac{R}{2} \rightarrow \frac{R}{\sqrt{2}} \angle \frac{-\pi}{4} $$

---

#### 4.B

Here is where I have trouble. In order to compute \$I_{2}\$, I decided I should try using: $$I_{2} = \frac{V_{1} - V_{2}}{Z_{2}}$$ with:

1. $$ V_{1} = V_{s} + 0j $$
2. $$ V_{2} = V_{1} \times \frac{Z_{3}}{Z_{3} + Z_{2}}$$

However this quickly blows up in my face and becomes a huge problem I can't manage. The given solution simply states:

$$I_{s} = \frac{V_{s}}{R} = \frac{V_{s}}{R}0.271 \angle \frac{\pi}{8}$$

and hints that it used some Norton equivalent circuit. How can I solve for this current using a Norton equivalent circuit? What am I missing about the problem?

---

Comment: @Tyler Yeah I know what it is. Mostly I would apply it to networks of energy sources and resistors (not sure how to deal with capacitors). Basically for Norton I would take two ports, and then short them. I would compute the short-circuit current as the voltage source / overall resistance. Then replace the circuit with a parallel resistor along with a current source.

Comment: So, the point is that your circuit 'b' includes a Norton source where 'a' had a Thevenin source.

Comment: Also I'm not clear how your answer for part (a) is correct, since the question asks for Z in terms of R and C, but you give the answer as a number. Where are the values for R and C given? I disagree with your answer for  a.1, but you could have the right numerical result depending on the R and C values.

Comment: @ThePhoton No you're right. My answer for $Z_{1}$ doesn't have any variables in it. I edited the problem to show how I derived it now. It turns out it is missing the term \$R\$ compared to the correct solution. I'm not sure how they got it :s.

Comment: Everything is going wrong :(

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for the theorem. I know about it already though. I'm just not sure what to do with it in this case really.

Comment: @Tyler I think I would get a Thévenin circuit with V_OC = I*Z1?

Comment: @Tyler Yeah. I get where you are going. The current will not be divided, so I2 = V / (Z1 + Z2 + Z3). However I'm not sure if this approach won't also "blow up". Actually I think it might work :)!